# How to convert string to float in ssis

Tags: ssis

How to convert the column `Quantite` in float in SSIS ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I will try to put it simple, assuming you are familiar with SSIS and Script Components*

Main problem is that your column contains leading 0's that makes it harder to parse the value to float.

**Solution 1**

You will first need to get rid of the leading 0's using a Derived Column component with fitting expression (could be complex)

Then pass that column through a data conversion component and set the data type to float

**Solution 2**

Pass original column through a script transform component, remove leading 0's and parse it to a new float column in the ProcessInputRow method using .NET

**C# Example:**

```
Row.new_column = float.Parse(Row.Quantite.TrimStart('0'));
```

Comment: in case your system doesn't use dots as decimal separator, you might need to replace the dot with a comma, Example: Row.Quantite.TrimStart('0').Replace('.', ',')